# Update Button Value

Tags: reactjs

I have problem to display updated value on a button. The original button text is "Filters". When clicking on the button, it changes to "SEE MATCHES xxx". xxx- stands for numbers, which is a total courses from this.state.Courses.length. There are a lot of other components, like checkboxes, radio boxes, when I select the other components, it will update the total courses. I have no clue to concatenate the text with numbers. Right now the button text always displays as "SEE MATCHES 0". If I change value={this.state.mobileBtnText+this.state.Courses.length} then it displays "SEE MATCHES 0xxx". Below is my code:

```
import React, {Component } from 'react';
import BtnMobile from './BtnMobile';
class App extends Component  {
     this.state={
     mobileBtnText:'Filters',
     Courses:0 //this value dynamically changes by selecting other components
     }
 //button click handler
onMobileClick=(totalCourses)=>{
     if (this.state.mobileBtnText==='Filters')
       {
         this.setState({mobileBtnText:'SEE MATCHES '+totalCourses});
       }
    else{
       this.setState({mobileBtnText:'Filters'});
     }
   }
render(){
    return(<div>
     <BtnMobile id="show-for-mobile"  value={this.state.mobileBtnText} totalCourses={this.state.Courses.length} onClick={this.onMobileClick}  /> 
    ....
    </div>)
     }
 }
```

// BtnMobile

```
import React,{Component}  from 'react';
const BtnMobile=({value,onClick,totalCourses})=>{
return (
    <div><input type="button" value={value}  onClick={()=>onClick(totalCourses)}/></div>
)
}
export default BtnMobile;
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can simply do this in your value field of the button.`value={ `SEE MATCHES ${this.state.Courses}` }`.

Comment: Thanks. But this generates syntax error.

Comment: that is a typo with my comment, you can do this instead of the above, `value={"SEE MATCHES " + this.state.Courses}`. Also, read about string literals in js, which will make concatenation easier

Comment: Thanks, but how to display the numbers when it is not 0?  I tried this {"SEE MATCHES" + this.state.Courses!==0? this.state.Courses.length:''}  and the button always displays as 0.

Comment: You set Courses to 0 and then you get the length of Courses ... is this variable a number or an array?

Comment: usually, the value of your course will be 0 and during some actions on other components, you need to update the courses value in state.

Comment: this.state.Courses is array of data. If I do {"SEE MATCHES"+ this.state.Courses.length}, the button will be "SEE MATCHES 0". When the Courses number is updated by other components, the button will be "SEE MATCHES 050", "SEE MATCHES 02", etc. I want to remove the 0 but how? Thanks.